# Find the line and there the level, that contains a bigger number than the input

Tags: regex, bash

I fail to find a regex that returns for a given input, e.g., 1000000000 the result 214.

Here is the text I need to regex:

```
lvl=100 (2626 KB for nbparts) 9522 possible passwords
lvl=101 (2652 KB for nbparts) 10 K possible passwords (10604)
lvl=102 (2678 KB for nbparts) 11 K possible passwords (11805)
...
lvl=213 (5564 KB for nbparts) 956 M possible passwords (956026029)
lvl=214 (5590 KB for nbparts) 1 G possible passwords (1058500959)
lvl=215 (5616 KB for nbparts) 1 G possible passwords (1171975083)
...
lvl=400 (10426 KB for nbparts) 29926014 G possible passwords (29926014173292546)
```

I need to find the level (lvl=) that corresponds to the number in the bracket () that is bigger than the input, e.g., for the input 1000000000 it would be 214, because 1058500959 is bigger than 1000000000. For this Job I'm limited to Bash scripting and I would love to use grep -E (“basic,” (BRE) “extended” (ERE) and “perl”) or similar standard GNU Linux tools, which are pre-installed on Ubuntu.

The input can be in the range of

```
1                 => lvl=101 
10000000000000000 => lvl=400
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -ne 'BEGIN { $trsh = shift }
          ($lvl, $pswd) = /lvl=([0-9]+).*\(([0-9]+)\)$/;
          print "$lvl $pswd\n" and exit if $pswd > $trsh;
         ' 1000000000 input.txt
```

In the regex, there are two capture groups, the matching strings are assigned to variables $lvl and $pswd. If $pswd is greater than $trsh (assigned from the first parameter at the beginning), the details are printed and the script ends.

Comment: You are awesome! Thanks a lot. I wonder if perl is installed on every Linux?